# How to Join a String recursively in a Loop in PHP

Tags: php

I am reading some JSON data and want to return it as a text from a function. For that, I am doing the following.

```
<?php

    $json = '{"Business":["Accounting","Macroeconomics"],"0":["English","English","Other","Penmanship"],"Math":["Calculus","Fractions","Functions"],"Other":["Geography","Philosophy"],"Science":["Geology","Physical Science"]}';
    
    $json1 = json_decode($json, true);
    
    
    function rex($json){
        
        foreach ($json as $key=>$value){
            $x='<tr>
                <td style="width:30%;font-weight:700;padding-bottom:10px">'.$key.'</td>
                <td>'.implode(' ,',$value).'</td>
               </tr>';
           echo $x;
        }
    }
    
    rex($json1);
    
    ?>
```

I can't figure out how to generate a final concatenated string from the function. If I `echo` it then it returns what I want but how to capture that output inside a variable. `$x.=$x` doesn't help either. I am a beginner in PHP these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` from the function and use concatenation.

```
...
function rex($json){
  $x = '';
  foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    $x .= '
    <tr>
      <td style="width:30%;font-weight:700;padding-bottom:10px">'.$key.'</td>
      <td>'.implode(', ',$value).'</td>
    </tr>';
  }
  return $x;  
}
    
echo rex($json1);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. One more thing if you can help. Can I call this function inside `strtr()` to add the generated table rows in the page?

Comment: np, I not sure what you mean, I happy to tweak it if you want to update your question (though if it's too diff better to ask another)

Comment: I'll ask okay if I can't figure it out myself.